# How to prevent onmouseout function to get called when onclick has been called already?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a Like button with an `input` with the type `image` which its `src` changes when it is hovered/clicked. I want to change it when it is hovered and have its previous source back when it is unhoverd. So I used `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` to do this. I also used `onclick` to the src when it is clicked on.

The problem is that when I click on it, it changes as intended but as soon as I move the mouse so it is not hovered anymore, It calls the `onmouseout` function and this is not what I need.

Edit: There are multiple buttons so I cant't use a boolean variables to check if was clicked.

What should I do to not execute `onmouseout` when it was clicked on?

```html
<input type="image" src="path" onmouseover="likeHover(this)" onmouseout="likeUnhover(this)" onclick="like(this, '{{post.id}}')">
```

```js
function likeHover(btn) {
    btn.src = '../../static/network/img/heart-pink.png';
}

function likeUnhover(btn) {
    btn.src = '../../static/network/img/heart-black.png';
}

function like(btn) {
    btn.src = '../../static/network/img/heart-red-filled.png';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a boolean variable, and set it to true if the button was clicked.
And use `addEventListener` in the JS code and not the HTML attributes:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input[type=image]");
  let clicked = false;

input.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
  if (!clicked)
    e.target.src = '../../static/network/img/heart-pink.png';
});

input.addEventListener("mouseout", (e) => {
  if (!clicked)
    e.target.src = '../../static/network/img/heart-black.png';
});

input.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  clicked = true;
  e.target.src = '../../static/network/img/heart-red-filled.png';
});
```

```html
<input type="image" src="path">
```